# Do exist a list of json-models for webgl?

Tags: json, 3d-model

I have a json 3D model(teapot) from [learningwebgl](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1658)

It works fine in webgl, but I can't find any site with json models. There are many sites with format such as .dae, .obj. But the converter(from obj to json) which I found in the Internet don't work right, therefore I need exactly json models. 
May be somebody knows sites(or github pages) with json 3D models?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing is *"json-models for WebGL"*. [WebGL is just a rasterization library](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-vs-3d-library.html). To draw a model in WebGL requires lots of user supplied code and/or a library. That code/library interprets whatever files you give it. WebGL itself has no concept of "models".

So, maybe you want models for three.js? Or maybe you want models for some code on learningwebgl? But there's no "models for WebGL".

As for learningwebgl in particular I haven't looked at their format but I suspect you probably either want to use a more common format or you need tools that convert from other formats to the format used by to code on learningwebgl.

Comment: I understood. And this is bad that json-models don't exist, since my converters from other format to json don't work. And I can't use Three.js by the task.

Answer (score 1):

as alread mentioned in other answers, you won't find very much json-models out there, most of them are in other formats, like .obj.

have a look at https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader
you can use it for converting obj-models for using them in your webgl code.

> A simple script to help bring OBJ models to your WebGL world. I originally wrote this script for my CS Graphics class so that we didn't have to only have cubes and spheres for models in order to learn WebGL. At the time, the only sort of model loader for WebGL was Mr. Doob's ThreeJS. And in order to use the loaders you had to use the entire framework (or do some very serious hacking and duct-taping in order get the model information). My main focus in creating this loader was to easily allow importing models without having to have special knowledge of a 3D graphics program (like Blender) while keeping it low-level enough so that the focus was on learning WebGL rather than learning some framework.

since you are working on a basic webgl tutorial, it's best to stick to plain webgl and not using any helping frameworks like three.js. with the webgl-obj-loader from github you can load obj-models into your own structures. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for link and answer. My previous converter didn't work right, I hope this one will be pretty working, I'll try it.